# Writing Monika poems in Doki Doki Literature Club?

Tags: doki-doki-literature-club

After Sayori's death, when you write poems, you only have Natsuki and Yuri chibis on the left.

However, when you click on certain words, you can see another chibi jumping. At first, I thought it was Sayori, but after triggering the chibi jump twice, accidentally of course, I have noticed straight hair and white ribbon, such as Monika's.

I am sure that I am not the only one who noticed it, but not sure if anybody was able to make a Monika poem out of it, which may have changed the story if you manage to spend some time with her.

If you were able to make a Monika poem, what would be the words she is interested in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this wiki source](https://ddlcwiki.ga/wiki/Poem_game), there is no possibility to make a poem for Monika, as all words have a different score for different characters, but none has a score for Monika. The source says:

> Every word is internally assigned a score for each character. The
>  character which the word most appeals to is indicated in-game by their
>  sticker at the bottom of the screen jumping when the word is selected.

A table is then displayed with all words and their corresponding scores, but Monika is not present in that table.

According to [this French source](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-3012602-54945438-1-0-1-0-un-poeme-pour-monika.htm), what you noticed is a known (or intended?) bug:

Original:

> Tu ne peux pas faire un poème pour Monika, la tête qui apparaît est
>  juste un petit bug sympathique qui se produit à 9% pour chaque mot
>  choisi.

Translated:

> You can't write a poem for Monika, the head appearing is only a bug
>  with 9% chance occurring for each chosen word.

Comment: I was able to proc the jump 4 times in a row so I thought it would be a possibility... well nevermind that, thanks

Comment: @gl_prout well I guess you were lucky then!

Comment: yep, too bad it was luck that led to nowhere :)

Comment: @gl_prout Could that nowhere be considered as an answer to your question?

Comment: yeah sure, just waiting for the 24 hours before validating your answer

Comment: owww, I didn't know there was such a limit! clever move, from Arqade :)

Comment: there isn't but it's just some politeness behavior in case someone else has an answer

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed impossible.

> Monica can only be triggered on the last days minigame in the second act.
>  After this minigame Monica will not read your poem (in all possible timelines)
>  and thus not even know you wrote it for her.
>  When she jumps up the initial girl will receive the points.

You can test that by accessing the scripts.rpa file, changing the values for the words to 0 and only a few to 1. Triggering a word with 1 will reward the points as normal, altering the feedback on your poems by Natsuki.

Answer (score 0):

The words you choose have no effect on Monika. According to the [DDLC wiki page on Easter Eggs](https://doki-doki-literature-club.fandom.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs):

> Upon selecting a word for the poem minigame on Day 3 of Act 2, there is a 1/11 (9.09%) chance for a Monika sticker to jump from underneath the screen.

Since its normally off-screen, the full Monika jumping sticker is below.

[image: Monika jumping]